# AAC license required for iPhone app?

Tags: ios, audio, mp3, aac

AAC is an audio codec which was "Designed to be the successor of the MP3 format, AAC generally achieves better sound quality than MP3 at similar bit rates." ([AAC on Wikipedia](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Advanced_Audio_Coding)).

However, similarly to MP3, parts of the AAC codec are patented, which means you can't simply use these codecs in all situations without making sure you are licensed to do so.
This is also true if you developed your own encoder or decoder. This is because writing an own encoder or decoder frees you only from copyright issues and software licenses (because you hold the copyright), but it doesn't free you from requirements imposed on you by patents.

Do I need to acquire a license for my iPhone app, which can encode and/or decode AAC files?

> This question is helpful to many developers, but it is not a good
>   example of an appropriate question for Stackoverflow. Read and learn
>   from this post, but please do not use it as evidence that you can ask
>   similar questions.
>
> See [About Stackoverflow](https://stackoverflow.com/about) for more information.

Comment: I'm fully aware that this question does not adhere to the SO guidelines. However, I've included it here because it can't be disputed that the answer is useful for many programmers. Moreover, it does not draw undesired opinionated answers or assumptions, because a definitive answer is already given. In the end, it will do more good than harm. Please, instead of closing or downvoting it, consider protecting it or moving it to community documentation.

Answer (score 7):

As long as you use the integrated encoders and/or decoders, you do not need to acquire your own license for using the AAC codec on the iPhone.

I've contacted [vialicensing.com](http://www.vialicensing.com/licensing/aac-overview.aspx) about this and they replied:

> If your app uses the integrated decoder of the iPhone, no license is
>   required. If however, you are providing a separate decoder as part of
>   your product you will need to obtain a license for every unit shipped.

Moreover, also about encoders:

> that also applies to recording using the integrated encoder of the
>   iPhone. Providing an encoder and/or decoder is what requires the
>   patent license. If a product relies on the integrated encoder/decoder
>   in a device it is the device brand owner which is required to fulfill
>   the license obligation.

Still, because this is a legal topic rather than a programming topic, you should contact via licensing if you have any uncertainties about your specific app.

Comment: Note that this is not the same with the MP3 format. MP3 is licensed with a different scheme by a different institution. Moreover, at the time of writing (iOS 7), the iPhone does not have an integrated MP3 encoder (it only has a decoder), so if you want to encode into MP3, you are forced to include an implementation of an encoder with your app.